# getting dot products from numpy arrays and tuples simultaneously

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I am trying to combine different parts of arrays and tuples to generate a series of products. Here is the tuple 'i':

```
i=(2,5)
```

Here is the first matrix 'w':

```
w=[array([[-1.95446441,  1.53904854, -0.3461807 ],
          [-0.19153855, -1.63290931, -1.76897156]]), 
   array([[ 0.25648535],
          [ 0.20186475],
          [ 0.78002102]])]
```

here is the second matrix 'b':

```
[array([[-0.02676943],
        [ 0.25294377],
        [-0.43625132]]), 
 array([[ 0.07763943]])]
```

I am trying to make a series of products from various parts of these datastructures in a list of lists or matrix called 'a'.

The list of these products should be equivalent to:

```
a[0][0] = (w[0][0][0]*i[0]) + (w[0][1][0]*i[1]) + b[0][0]
a[0][1] = (w[0][0][1]*i[0]) + (w[0][1][1]*i[1]) + b[0][1]
a[0][2] = (w[0][0][2]*i[0]) + (w[0][1][2]*i[1]) + b[0][2]

a[1][0] = (w[1][0] * a[0][0]) + (w[1][1] * a[0][1]) + (w[1][2] * a[0][2]) + b[1][0]
```

I am trying to use this as part of a neural network and have written a version that works perfectly well using iteration. However I am new to numpy and would like to build a matrix based version of this. The problem I am having is more to do with understanding the numpy syntax to perform the operation above. I tried adapting this from an online tutorial but am not sure where to go from here.

```
for b, w in zip(b, w):
     layer = sigmoid(np.dot(w, layer)+b.T)
     a.append(layer)
```

This throws and error:

```
ValueError: shapes (2,3) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Any pointers would be very helpful?

Comment: The error is quite clear, the matrix dimensions don't match. You are trying to compute the product of a 2x3 matrix and a 1x3 matrix. I suppose you should do `np.dot(w, np.tranpose(layer))`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes I understand why the error occurs but its the syntax rather than the computation. If you look at what I have detailed above, particularly the last section 'a[1][0] = (w[1][0] * a[0][0]) + (w[1][1] * a[0][1]) + (w[1][2] * a[0][2]) + b[1][0]' this is what I am trying to achieve but just dont know how to get numpy to do this in a generalized form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start let's split your 2 variables, `w` and `b`.  They aren't really arrays, they are lists of arrays with different shapes

```
w0 = array([[-1.95446441,  1.53904854, -0.3461807 ],
          [-0.19153855, -1.63290931, -1.76897156]]) 
w1 = array([[ 0.25648535],
          [ 0.20186475],
          [ 0.78002102]])

b0 = array([[-0.02676943],
        [ 0.25294377],
        [-0.43625132]])
b1 = array([[ 0.07763943]])
```

Maybe later you can iterate over them as 2 element lists, but for now that  just complicates things.

Now your `a` calculation simplifies to:

```
a0[0] = w0[0,0]*i[0] + w0[1,0]*i[1] + b0[0]
a0[1] = w0[0,1]*i[0] + w0[1,1]*i[1] + b0[1]
a0[2] = w0[0,2]*i[0] + w0[1,2]*i[1] + b0[2]

a1[0] = w1[0]* a0[0] + w1[1]*a0[1] + w1[2]*a0[2] + b1[0]
```

which further simplifies to:

```
a0 = w0[0,:]*i[0] + w0[1,:]*i[1] + b0
a1 = np.sum(w1*a0) + b1
```

or

```
I0 = np.array([i]).T
a0 = np.sum(w0*i0, axis=0) + b0
```

Those sums could be turned into dots; I think this works:

```
a0 = np.dot(w0.T,i) + b0
```

But I doubt if it's much of an improvement.

You can't calculate `a0` and `a1` together, since the one uses the other. But you could cast it as an iteration like (not tested):

```
I0 = ...
w = [w0,w1]
b = [b0,b1]
a = [None,None]
for i in range(...):
   a[i] = np.sum(w[i]*I0, axis=0) + b[i]
   I0 = a[i]
```

Comment: This is really helpful how you have shown each step, it makes it very easy to see what the code is doing. Yes I figured 'a' would have to be calculated in batches, I wanted to use numpy to calculate each batch which you've definitely improved my understanding of. Many thanks.